# Issue with bash prompt wrapping

Tags: bash, prompt

I know that non printing characters can mess with bash's wrapping behaviour, but I've been looking at my PS1 for awhile now and it doesn't seem to have any issues.

Here is my prompt code in my `.bashrc`:

```
reset="\[\033(B\033[m\]" 
fgblack="\[\033[30m\]" 
bgblack="\[\033[40m\]" 
fgred="\[\033[31m\]" 
bgred="\[\033[41m\]" 
fggreen="\[\033[32m\]" 
bggreen="\[\033[42m\]" 
fgyellow="\[\033[33m\]" 
bgyellow="\[\033[43m\]" 
fgblue="\[\033[34m\]" 
bgblue="\[\033[44m\]" 
fgmagenta="\[\033[35m\]" 
bgmagenta="\[\033[45m\]" 
fgcyan="\[\033[36m\]" 
bgcyan="\[\033[46m\]" 
fgwhite="\[\033[37m\]" 
bgwhite="\[\033[47m\]" 
bolded="\[\033[1m\]" 
dim="\[\033[2m\]" 
italic="\[\033[3m\]" 
underlined="\[\033[4m\]" 

PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command

__prompt_command() {
    local EXIT="$?"
    PS1="${bolded}[ ${fgblue}\w ${reset}${bolded}]\n"

    if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
        PS1+="${fgblack}${bgwhite}"
    else 
        PS1+="${fggreen}"
    fi

    PS1+="\u${reset}@${fgmagenta}\h ${reset}\$ "
}
```

Can anyone spot the reason for my stereotypical bash wrapping issue?

Comment: can you snapshot as it is now, and another snapshot as you'd like it to be? not sure what you want.

Comment: Let's pretend my terminal is 5 characters wide for argument sake. What I want: `one t` (EOL) `wo!`, what I have: `wo! t`.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Bash: Multiple line PS1 prompt doubles up when redrawing #490](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/490).

Comment: I know a similar issue from serial lines but I guess this is not the problem here.

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I suspect it's the `\n` you have in it. Bash is calculating the width and is including the length of both lines, not just the second.